# Cannot Insert Opportunity In Test Class When Splits Are Enabled

Tags: unit-test, opportunity, opportunity-teams, opportunity-split

We have Splits enabled in our org.
I would like to insert an Opportunity and to assign it to a user that have Opportunity Team Members configured in his user details, so Salesforce will insert all Opportunity Team Members automatically.

I have tried this in another org and same error.
Is this a bug? any workaround ?

I have tried to create a new user and to create UserTeamMember records but it's not possible.

Thanks,

Appreciate your help.

[image]

```
    private static testMethod void accountOwnerChangeTest() {

    List<User> accountOwners = [SELECT Id, (SELECT UserId FROM UserAccountTeams) FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM UserAccountTeamMember) LIMIT 2];
    List<User> opportunityOwners = [SELECT Id, (SELECT UserId FROM UserTeams) FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM UserTeamMember) LIMIT 1];

    if(accountOwners.size() != 2 || opportunityOwners.size() != 1) {
        return;
    }

    User accountOwner = accountOwners.get(0);
    User newAccountOwner = accountOwners.get(1);
    User oppportunityOwner = opportunityOwners.get(0);

    Account acc = objectCreator.createAccount();
    acc.OwnerId = accountOwner.Id;
    insert acc;

    Opportunity opp = objectCreator.createOpportunity(acc.Id);
    opp.OwnerId = oppportunityOwner.Id;
    insert opp;

}
```